# When does docker update images?

Tags: docker

If I have an image like `python:latest`, when will docker check with the repo to see if the tag now points to a newer image, and download that new image?

I know it will do it if:

- The image isn't found on your local machine, and you try to run a container using that image
- You explicitly run `docker pull python:latest`

Are there other times docker will update the image? When the docker daemon restarts? When the system restarts (which is probably the same as the docker daemon restarting)? When docker is updated (from apt/dnf repos)?

At one point, it looked like we had a case at our company where we didn't pin a particular version of an image (used `:latest`), and after a system update, docker grabbed a new version of the image, and things broke. Clearly version pinning is important in production, but not the point of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the image already exists in the local docker engine, docker will not pull it again unless requested. There are flags to request the image gets pulled again on some commands. Otherwise, if you see the image change, I would look for either a `docker pull` command being run, or the images getting cleaned (e.g. with a prune command).